# Heapsort algorithm performing poorly compared to another

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, heapsort

I have two `heapsort` algorithms. The first one is written by me, while the 2nd one is taken from some website. According to me, both have the same logic, but the 2nd one is performing way better than the first. Any reason why is this happening? The only difference I can see is that mine uses a recursion, while the other one does it iteratively. Can that alone be the differentiating factor?

My code:

```
def heapify(arr,i,n):
    pivot = arr[i]   #the value of the root node
    left,right = (i<<1)+1,(i<<1)+2  #indices of the left and right subtree root nodes
    if right <= n-1:  #if right is within the array, so is left
        if arr[left] <= pivot and arr[right] <= pivot:
            return  #if both are less than the root node, it's already heapified
        maximum = left if arr[left] >= arr[right] else right #else find which child has a higher value
        arr[maximum],arr[i] = arr[i],arr[maximum]  #swap the root node with that child
        return heapify(arr,maximum,n)  #make the changed child the new root and recurse
    else:
      if left <= n-1:  #right is outside the array, so check for left only
        if arr[left] <= pivot:
            return
        arr[i],arr[left] = arr[left], arr[i]  #same logic as above
        return heapify(arr,left,n)
      else:
          return

def heapit(array,n):
    for i in range((len(array)-1)/2,-1,-1):  #all elements after (len(array)-1)/2 are the leaf nodes, so we have to heapify earlier nodes
        heapify(array,i,n)

def heapsort(array):
    n = len(array)
    for i in range(n,0,-1):
        heapit(array,i)  #make the array a heap
        array[0],array[i-1] = array[i-1],array[0]  #swap the root node with the last element
```

The other code:

```
def HeapSort(A):
     def heapify(A):
        start = (len(A) - 2) / 2
        while start >= 0:
            siftDown(A, start, len(A) - 1)
            start -= 1

     def siftDown(A, start, end):
        root = start
        while root * 2 + 1 <= end:
            child = root * 2 + 1
            if child + 1 <= end and A[child] < A[child + 1]:
                child += 1
            if child <= end and A[root] < A[child]:
                A[root], A[child] = A[child], A[root]
                root = child
            else:
                return

     heapify(A)
     end = len(A) - 1
     while end > 0:
        A[end], A[0] = A[0], A[end]
        siftDown(A, 0, end - 1)
        end -= 1
```

Even for small array with size about 100,000, the difference becomes substantial. I am invoking either code through just passing the array to be sorted to the function: `HeapSort(list)` or `heapsort(list)`.

Edit:

I have replaced the `heapsort` function by this one:

```
def heapsort(array):
     n = len(array)
     heapit(array,n)
     array[n-1],array[0] = array[0],array[n-1]
     for i in range(n-1):
       heapify(array,0,n-1-i)
       array[n-i-2],array[0] = array[0],array[n-i-2]
```

This gives a comparable performance, but it is still slower. For a 1 million dollar array, the results are almost 20 seconds : 4 seconds. What else can be done?

Comment: On what sized? Did you statistically check it is indeed the case? If it is - the usual immidiate suspect is cache efficiency.

Comment: What is the performance difference by actual time for the same 100,000?

Comment: Both algorithms follow similar logic, so I guess the cache inefficiency will apply to them both. Regarding the size, I tested with just a 10,000 element list. Mine took almost 40 seconds, while the other took less than a second.

Comment: For 100,000 my program doesn't return the prompt for almost 15 minutes, so I just killed it! The other one took around 10 seconds.

Comment: Your function names are confusing. Is your "heapify" algorithm supposed to be the "trickle-down" step of heapifying?

Comment: Can you provide some comments for your code to lay out the general structure instead of having to read through everything? That would simplify analyzing the provided algorithms.

Comment: Just give me 5 minutes, I will add the comments. The `heapify` function assumes that the two children of node `i` are perfect heaps, but `i` itself may not be a heap, i.e one of the two children of node `i` may be larger than node `i`. So the function finds out which of the children is larger, then exchanges that child with `i`. Since that may render the child as un-heap in turn, that child is now root, and the function recurses.

Comment: Edited. Please see if it's clear now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**: my remarks below might explain a major slowdown, but the most important thing is that your algorithm *is not heapsort*.

Inside the function `heapsort`, you perform a loop `for i in range(n,0,-1)`. That's `n` iterations where `n` is the size of your input. Inside that loop, you call `heapit`, which loops `for i in range((len(array)-1)/2,-1,-1)`; that's roughly `n//2` iterations.

`n * (n // 2)` = Θ(`n`²). In other words, you have an algorithm that takes at least quadratic time, while the second algorithm implements the true heapsort, that runs in O(`n` lg `n`) time.

**/EDIT**

It's very likely the recursion that's killing performance, in combination with the calling of functions defined at the module level. Python (CPython at least) is not optimized for recursive programs, but for iterative ones. For every recursive call in `heapify`, CPython has to perform the following seven byte code instructions:

```
  9         158 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (heapify)
            161 LOAD_FAST                0 (arr)
            164 LOAD_FAST                6 (maximum)
            167 LOAD_FAST                2 (n)
            170 CALL_FUNCTION            3
            173 RETURN_VALUE        
        >>  174 POP_TOP
```

(determined using [`dis`](http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html)). The final two instructions are performed after the recursive call has finished, because [Python does **not** perform tail call optimization](http://neopythonic.blogspot.nl/2009/04/tail-recursion-elimination.html).

While this may not look expensive, a `LOAD_GLOBAL` has to do [at least one hash table lookup](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2006-August/068437.html) just to find `heapify`, and the reference counts for `heapify`, `arr`, `maximum` and `i` have to be incremented. When the recursive call finishes, the reference counts have to be decremented again. Function calling is pretty expensive in Python.

As `import this` says, "flat is better than nested": prefer iteration over recursion whenever possible.

Comment: Interesting, and a good answer. Can it be THAT significant? (difference from 40 secs to 15+ mins?) Or is it only a part of the problem in your opinion, based on your personal experience in python?

Comment: Exactly. Same question here, can it be THAT significant?

Comment: @amit: It may be only part of the problem; when I disassemble the second program, there are no `LOAD_GLOBAL` instructions in the loops, which can also be performance killers. Note that 40s vs. 15min (assuming the program was about to finish) is just one order of magnitude difference (a factor of 22.5), so a few optimization tricks should be enough to get such a speedup over a naive program.

Comment: @Cupidvogel: I just spotted one more thing. Are you on Python 2 or 3?

Comment: Python 2.7. Can even that be a factor?

Comment: Just a suggestion, it may be due to my system be clogged, can you test my code in you computer for an array of length say 10,000 and see if it is delayed just as much?

Comment: @Cupidvogel: never mind, Py 2 or 3 doesn't make much of a difference (although `range` may be slower than `xrange`). See edited answer.

Comment: Yeah, I know `xrange` may be slower than `range`, but I am constructing the array by importing `shuffle` from `random`, creating a `range(100000)`, and then doing `shuffle(array)`. The `shuffle` function doesn't work on `xrange` objects.

Comment: No, that can't be. The 2nd code's last part, `while end > 0:
` does the same thing. The `siftdown` function itself includes a `while` loop, so that puts a `while` loop inside another `while` loop, thus leading to the same `O(N^2)` time.

Comment: @Cupidvogel: in the 2nd program, the `while end>0` loop is outside of any other loop. Then, the `siftDown` loop only runs O(lg n) times, because it does `child = root * 2 + 1` and then `root = child`, skipping over half of the array in each iteration.

Comment: Effectively, it's the `insert` operation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Insert

Comment: Yeah, right, found the gotcha. The `heapit` function turns a random array into a heap, but after it has been turned into a heap, following the swapping of the root and the last element, only the first element now needs to be heapified. So I have to replace the `heapit` by `heapify` inside the `for` loop in my `heapsort` function.

Comment: I have edited the question. The modified code gives `O(N*log N)` time, but still is slower than the other one.

Comment: @Cupidvogel: for a factor of 5 difference, my analysis of recursion v. iteration holds. I tried implementing `range` both iteratively and recursively, and found a factor three difference. The final 1.67 factor must be due to implementation details (`range`, lots of accesses to the array, etc.).

Comment: Okay. So the only implementation difference between the two codes is the use of recursion, and that is causing the difference of 20:4, right? Both codes access arrays more or less, that perhaps contributes little to the difference.

Comment: @Cupidvogel: you don't know until you measure.